# Centering a UILabel and a UIImage in a UIView with programatic constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to create an interface like this:

[image]

However right now my code is generating one more like this:
[image]

Essentially the strategy is to create a center UIView function that sets the objects as a chain and then creates empty UIViews to their left and right that are equally maximally sized.

As you can see rather than the intended result the content is pushed as far right as possible. Any clue how I can fix this?

It would appear that the right view is not expanding at all. I did set their background colors to red and you could clearly see the left view expanded but the right view was not visible.

Please note that the text is of extremely variable length so no constants will work well here.

```
func setupUI() {
    let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        superView.addSubview(label)
        label.text = "Text"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "", size: 13)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.topAnchor, constant: -6).isActive = true
        label.setNeedsLayout()
        label.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

        let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "chevron.png"))
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        superView.addSubview(image)
        image.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        image.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        image.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        center(objects: [label, image], parent: superView, debug: true)
}

func center(objects: [UIView], parent: UIView, debug: Bool = false) {
    let sl = UIView()
    sl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    parent.addSubview(sl)

    let sr = UIView()
    sr.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    parent.addSubview(sr)


    // Grow as much as you can 
    sl.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    sr.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0).isActive = true


    // Stay on the same row as them
    sl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objects.first!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    sr.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objects.last!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


    // Set their height correctly
    sl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objects.first!.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    sr.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objects.last!.heightAnchor).isActive = true


    // Set them to hook into parent
    sl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    sr.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    // Get them to re-size (this seems to have no effect)
    sr.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal)
    sl.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal)

    // Hook in the first and last object
    objects.first!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sl.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    objects.last!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sr.leadingAnchor).isActive = true


    // Chain the objects together
    for i in 1..<objects.count {
        objects[i].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objects[i-1].trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a button for this.

Comment: While the image looks like it should be a button that is actually not the final image that is just a placeholder. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can place both your text and button inside a View and then center align that view to the super view horizontally or vertically.

Comment: How do I center align the objects within that view?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather wrap the label and image in a `UIStackView` and center that stack view in parent view.

```
func center(objects: [UIView], parent: UIView, debug: Bool = false) {
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: objects)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.alignment = .center
    parent.addSubview(stackView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.centerXAnchor),
      stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.centerYAnchor),
      stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: parent.widthAnchor),
      stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: parent.heightAnchor)
    ])
}
```